# ASP.Net C# ¿Cómo puedo consumir este Web Service WSDL desde C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, soap, wsdl

¿Cómo puedo consumir este WS?, al consumirlo desde SoapUI funciona todo perfecto, pero al tratar de hacerlo mediante código C# referenciando el WS y todo el proceso normal, el método **consultarCertificadoAfiliado** me dice que es VOID, no retorna nada y no admite parámetros.

- El método **consultarCertificadoAfiliado** funciona bien desde SoapUI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Al hacerlo desde el código muestra esto
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- La referencia quedó acá.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

============================

- la configuración la hice así, y esos son los 3 métodos del service pero en todos los métodos por alguna razón cuando los voy a usar dice que son Void y no me sugiere ningún parámetro.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Acá están los otros métodos pero en todos dice Void y sin uso de parámetros
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

==============================================

- Esto aparece al usar la herramienta WfcTestClient, probé con la misma herramienta otros WS y esos otros sí funcionan, pero el que necesito no
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Error: El estilo Rpc del encabezado request_header no coincide con el estilo esperado Document.Error: El estilo Rpc del encabezado response_header no coincide con el estilo esperado Document.Advertencia: No se puede importar el error con el nombre parameters en la operaci¢n consultarCertificadoAfiliadoPac. No se admite WSDL. La parte de mensaje de error debe hacer referencia a un elemento. Este mensaje de error no hace referencia a un elemento. Si tiene acceso de edici¢n al documento WSDL, puede corregir el problema haciendo referencia a un elemento de esquema mediante el atributo 'element'.Advertencia: No se puede importar el error con el nombre parameters en la operaci¢n consultarCertificadoAfiliado. No se admite WSDL. La parte de mensaje de error debe hacer referencia a un elemento. Este mensaje de error no hace referencia a un elemento. Si tiene acceso de edici¢n al documento WSDL, puede corregir el problema haciendo referencia a un elemento de esquema mediante el atributo 'element'.Advertencia: No se puede importar el error con el nombre parameters en la operaci¢n consultarCertificadoSemanasCotizadas. No se admite WSDL. La parte de mensaje de error debe hacer referencia a un elemento. Este mensaje de error no hace referencia a un elemento. Si tiene acceso de edici¢n al documento WSDL, puede corregir el problema haciendo referencia a un elemento de esquema mediante el atributo 'element'.c:\Users\brebuimi\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\16.0\dfc617e3-50dd-45d0-a853-f4ac73bd1d73\Client.cs(1290,84) : error CS0161: 'WSCertificadosClient.consultarCertificadoAfiliadoPac(www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.cabecera._1._01.cabeceraRequest, www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.mde.identificacion._1._01.identificacion, bool, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.mensajesGenericos._1._01.mensajeGenerico, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.pac.certificadoafiliado.datosCertificadoAfiliadoPac._1._01.datosCertificadoAfiliadoPac)': no todas las rutas de código devuelven un valor
>   c:\Users\brebuimi\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\16.0\dfc617e3-50dd-45d0-a853-f4ac73bd1d73\Client.cs(1324,84) : error CS0161: 'WSCertificadosClient.consultarCertificadoAfiliado(www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.cabecera._1._01.cabeceraRequest, www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.mde.identificacion._1._01.identificacion, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.mensajesGenericos._1._01.mensajeGenerico, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.mde.certificadoafiliado.datosCertificadoAfiliado._1._01.datosCertificadoAfiliado)': no todas las rutas de código devuelven un valor
>   c:\Users\brebuimi\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\16.0\dfc617e3-50dd-45d0-a853-f4ac73bd1d73\Client.cs(1356,84) : error CS0161: 'WSCertificadosClient.consultarCertificadoSemanasCotizadas(www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.cabecera._1._01.cabeceraRequest, www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.mde.identificacion._1._01.identificacion, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.tecnicos.mensajesGenericos._1._01.mensajeGenerico, out www.nuevaeps.com.co.canonicos.mde.certificadosemanascotizadas.datosCertificadoSemanasCotizadas._1._01.datosCertificadoSemanasCotizadas)': no todas las rutas de código devuelven un valor

Comment: Te muestra el resto de los metodos? y como esta la configuracion del servicio cuando lo traes?

Comment: puedes usar la herramienta que te provee Microsoft wcftestclient para probar tus metodos y ver los parametros de forma mas legible.

Comment: @RamiroBarone al crear el objeto e intentar acceder a sus propiedades y métodos sí me muestra los métodos del WS pero en todos dice que es void sin parámetros. Agregué imágenes a la pregunta para que veas si me puedes ayudar, gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes intentar agregarlo como Web reference en lugar de Service Reference? Esto lo haces en la ventana de Agregar Referencia de servicio/Avanzadas/Agregar Referencia Web (Web Reference). He encontrado problemas en ocasiones con algunos servicios que requieren ser agregados en formato "legacy".

Comment: Es que no hay nada mal en tu servicio, porque te muestra los metodos que la interface hace publicos para consumir. Lo agregas bien, seguro que la unica direccion del servicio es la que tienes?

Comment: @JavierReséndiz lo que indicas lo intenté pero de esa manera no me deja instanciar el objeto WScertificadosClient, ni poniendole using ni de ningún modo

Comment: @RamiroBarone apropósito de lo que mencionas de usar WcfTestClient, no sabía usarlo pero no es complicado, y al intentar usarlo con este WS aparece el error de la nueva imagen, creí que tal vez el WcfTestClient fallaba pero lo probé con otros WS y sí funciono, lo que supongo es que el WS tiene algo mal pero no sé que interpretación darle. en el siguiente comentario muestro literal el error

Comment: Si utilizas el modo "legacy", no te crea una instancia del Client, se utiliza otra clase. ¿Puedes compartir el wsdl completo que estás intentando referenciar? Si es un error como el que reporta el WCFTestClient, se puede revisar y detectar el problema.

Comment: El wcf lo creaste tu? deberias subir ese codigo, para poder verlo.

Comment: @RamiroBarone El service no es mio. Yo soy como un tercero, mi cliente tiene su grupo de desarrollo y sus bases de datos a las que no me dan acceso por seguridad, me piden hacer un desarrollo pero para no darme acceso a sus bases de datos me dan un WS para que me traiga solo los datos precisos, es el WS con el que tengo problemas.

Comment: @JavierReséndiz no entiendo muy bien lo que me pides (Compartir el WSDL completo) ni lo del legacy

Comment: podes compartime la direccion para probar?

Comment: Si pones http://192.168.96.6:6080/services/WS_Certificados?wsdl en el vavegador, te muestra el contrato del servicio (wsdl). Ese contrato es un XML a partir del cual Visual Studio genera el código para invocar el servicio. Puedes guardar ese archivo y compartir su contenido para analizarlo.

Comment: RamiroBarone  la dirección es de mi cliente y solo le dio acceso a mi maquina y al servidor donde debo publicar; @JavierReséndiz yo sí puedo ver el xml en el navegador, dejo el archivo en este link https://github.com/bredybuitrago/compartida/blob/master/WS_Certificados.xml

Comment: Veo que el wsdl no viene completo, incluye referencias a esquemas externos. ¿Puedes probar con el siguiente link http://192.168.96.6:6080/services/WS_Certificados?singlewsdl ? Ahí debería descargar incluso el contenido de esquemas externos en un solo archivo. Sin esas referencias no se puede analizar...

Comment: @JavierReséndiz tenés razón, intenté con el singlewsdl y me aparece
> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Al intentarlo con otro WS sí me muestra los metodos y demás información, No entiendo que pasa.

Comment: No importa el mensaje de estilo. El documento lo puedes ver de todos modos (View Source) y lo puedes guardar en tu equipo. Una vez que lo hagas, puedes actualizarlo en el repositorio .git y con ese se puede proceder a revisarlo.

Comment: Has podido solucionarlo? Estoy atascado en algo similar-

Comment: Hola, pudiste resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tengas que crear un objeto `consultarCertificadoAfiliadoRequest` y enviarlo como parametro

```
var r = new consultarCertificadoAfiliadoRequest();
r.tipo_documento = "CC";
r.numero_documento = "1234";
```

y luego llamar al metodo con ese objeto:

```
var datos = ws.consultarCertificadoAfiliado(r);
```

Comment: No podria enviar eso, porque ese es el nombre del Metodo. Si le recibe algun objeto seria del tipo identificacion_afiliado.

Comment: Fijate que Visual Studio te ofrece mostrarte los posible parametros que acepta el metodo (cliquear en Mostrar posibles correcciones)

Comment: me dice que el método consultarCertificadoAfiliadoRequest()  "Terminado en Request" no se encontró, como si no existiera.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni no me muestra ningún posible parámetro como si el método no usara parámetros y no retornara nada

Comment: Claro que no va a funcionar porque no es un Tipo, es un metodo.